# Regular expression for R, insert a letter after any digits

Tags: regex, r, formula

While constructing a new model formulation, I encounter the need to modify a ordinary glm model frame, such as `Y~ x1+x2+I(x1*x2)+I(x1^2)` to `Y~ x1m+x2m+I(x1m*x2m)+I(x1m^2)`. Basically what I need is to insert a letter after a digit in the design matrix. So from `c('x1','x2','I(x1*x2)','I(x1^2)')` to `c('x1m','x2m','I(x1m*x2m)','I(x1m^2'))` in a generic way.

I've been struggling with this problem for a more than a day, any suggestion will be appreciated!

Liv

Comment: Why `m` isn't added after to the last 2?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this,

```
> x <- c('x1','x2','I(x1*x2)','I(x1^2)')
> gsub("(?<!\\^)(\\d)", "\\1m", x, perl=T)
[1] "x1m"        "x2m"        "I(x1m*x2m)" "I(x1m^2)"
```

This `(?<!\\^)(\\d)` regex would capture all the digits which are not preceded by `^` symbol. Replacing the matched digits with the digits in  group index 1 plus the letter `m` will give the desired output.

Comment: need to add a condition that doesn't add an m if the digit is being exponentiated or simply `gsub('(?<=x\\d)', 'm', m1, perl = TRUE)`

Comment: see my update.. You don't need to add `x` in the regex.

Comment: you do if you dont want an m put in after every digit not proceeded by a ^. Plus OP wanted a formula, too

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thanks, but I got error message from R - 'Error: unexpected '>' in ">"'

Comment: @Liv it works for me. Did you try with the input i specified? And also you need to add more details in your question about why you don't want to add `m` after a digit which was preceded by `^`?